# Is there a way to retrieve a PowerShell function name from within a function?

Tags: function, reflection, powershell

For example:

```
function Foo { 
    [string]$functionName = commandRetrievesFoo
    Write-Host "This function is called $functionName"
}
```

Output:

```
PS > Foo
This function is called foo
```

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `$MyInvocation` which contains some useful information about what is currently executed.

```
function foo {
    'This function is called {0}.' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand
}
```

Comment: That works - thanks any idea how to get the calling function name? I tried other $myInvocation properties but I don't see one.                           function foo { 'This function is called {0}.' -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand
               'This Caller is called {0}.' -f $MyInvocation.? }
function CallFoo { foo }
CallFoo

Comment: If you are on PowerShell 2.0 use `(Get-PSCallStack)[1].Command`.

Comment: Make that a separate question, so people can find it. The answer in v1 is in `gv -sc $_ myinvocation`. See http://jtruher.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!7143DA6E51A2628D!172.entry

Comment: I've come across two methods of getting the calling function name: 1) `(Get-PSCallStack | Select-Object FunctionName -Skip 1 -First 1).FunctionName` and 2) `(Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value.MyCommand.Name`.  I tried running each in a loop 1000 times to see how long each took.  The Get-Variable... method takes about half the time of the Get-PSCallStack... method.

Comment: @Simon: Hardly surprising, considering that `Get-PsCallStack` likely has to create a complete call stack at that moment instead of just having to look up once in the nested scopes. However I doubt this is ever performance relevant. If it were you wouldn't write your code to be dynamic around the function names, or even use PowerShell at all.

Comment: Technically, you should use `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name`. `$MyInvocation.MyCommand` works in the given example because it returns the function's name when you convert it to a string.

Comment: `$MyInvocation` cannot be used to get the name of a function within a class. To do this, I needed to use `Get-PSCallStack)[0].FunctionName`

Comment: Confirmed this works in PS v5 and PS v7.4 ~ hth

Answer (score 14):

Easy.

```
function Get-FunctionName ([int]$StackNumber = 1) {
    return [string]$(Get-PSCallStack)[$StackNumber].FunctionName
}
```

By default *Get-FunctionName* in the example will get the name of the function that called it.

```
Function get-foo () {
    Get-FunctionName
}
get-foo
#Reutrns 'get-foo'
```

Increasing the *StackNumber* parameter will get the name of the next function call up.

```
Function get-foo () {
    Get-FunctionName -StackNumber 2
}
Function get-Bar  () {
    get-foo 
}
get-Bar 
#Reutrns 'get-Bar'
```

Comment: I'm using this feature in a logging function so being able to chose the $StackNumber to access the name of the caller is practical. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

When you are in a function you can access the automatic variable $[PSCmdLet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.management.automation.pscmdlet(v=vs.85).aspx).

This is an extremely useful variable that holds a lot of information about the currently executing cmdlet.

In our scenario we wanted the name and the definition of the current function for some recursion. $MyInvocation was null because the function was within a PowerShell module.

However, there is a "MyInvocation" property on the PSCmdLet object which contains all the information needed and allowed our scenario to run.

e.g. 
$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.MyCommand.Name = The name of the function
$PSCmdlet.MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition = The definition of the function

Comment: `$PSCmdlet` appears to only work if the function has an explicit `[CmdletBinding()]` attribute.

Comment: The [about_automatic_variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-5.1) entry for $PsCmdlet says `Contains an object that represents the cmdlet or advanced function that is being run`.  So it only works with advanced functions, which have the CmdletBindingAttribute, not normal functions.

Answer (score 2):

The `Get-PSCallStack` option seems to work only once: when calling a function from the body of the script, the first time it will retrieve the script name, but the second time it will retrieve the text ''

Comment: Seems to be repeatable to me, returning the call stack each time I call it.  I wanted to find the name of the calling function and using Get-PSCallStack seems to be the way to do it; the method in Jay Bazuzi's link didn't give me the calling function name.  For anyone else, I used `Get-PSCallStack | Select-Object FunctionName -Skip 1 -First 1` to get the name of the calling function.  If the current function is called from the top level script this will return '<ScriptBlock>'.