# Display the name of the currently executing function

Tags: powershell

How can I retrieve the name of the function that is currently running in powershell? Here is an example of what I want:

```
Function write-FunctionName
{
write-host "The name of this function is: *SomethingGoesHereButWhat?*"
}
```

Then when I execute it, it will display this:

```
>write-FunctionName

The name of this function is: write-FunctioName

>
```

Can this be done? If so how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to retrieve a PowerShell function name from within a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689543/is-there-a-way-to-retrieve-a-powershell-function-name-from-within-a-function)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `$MyInvocation` variable contains information about whatever is currently executing:

```
Function write-FunctionName
{
    write-host ("The name of this function is: {0} " -f $MyInvocation.MyCommand)
}
```

For more information, see `get-help about_automatic_variables`, or the technet site [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768).